# Where to upload cgi script on Linux Debian VPS with Plesk?

Tags: linux, debian, hosting, vps

I'm newbie to Linux.

I have uploaded rebol ( a script langage similar to perl from http://www.rebol.com/view-platforms.html ) the linux debian version to /usr/bin on my VPS

Where do I upload this script :

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/rebol -c
REBOL [Title: "Cgi Test in Rebol"]
print "content-type: text/html^/"
print ["Date/time is:" now]
```

as I have 2 domain names on this VPS, I can't find where the domain folder are to do so.

Comment: Look for a cgi-bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (and probably Debian too) this is located in

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin
```

That's assuming that you have Apache installed.

The stock Apache config aliases `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` to `servername.com/cgi-bin`. If you've changed that in the course of setting up your virtual servers, that may not work. But you should be able to look at the example in the config and get it working for your virtual servers.

Answer (score 1):

On plesk I think it should be something like:

```
/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/cgi-bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like Coops said if your VPS uses Plesk the location is:

`/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/cgi-bin`

But don't forget to enable CGI support for the domain in "web hosting settings"